# Submit app on Windows Phone Store Brazil

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

I try to submit an app on All Windows phone Stores but i don't know why the app is unavailable on the brazilian store, I have the message "Esse aplicativo não está disponível em seu mercado." (*This application is not available in your market.*) and there is no way to download the app.

I have found some tutorials explaining that a certification is needed to post an app on the brazilian store. So, I have joined a PEGI certification with the app but there is no change, the app is always unavailable.

So, is there a delay for the validation or have I missed something ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please translate your message to English?

Comment: "This application is not available in your market."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finaly found a solution to my problem.

When we want send an app, in the windows phone dev center, we have three choice for the Marcket Distribution in the description of the app : 
-"Distribute to all available marckets at the base price tier",
-"Distribute to all marckets except China"
-"Continue distributing to current marckets"

When I have published my app for the first time, I have selected "*Distribute to all available marcket at the base price tier*" but I didn't upload the brazilian's certificate because app was juste available on the French store.
And, when I have wanted publish the app on the brazilian store, I have just selected "*Continue distributing to current markets*".
So I think that when I have published app for the first time, an list of the available country have been generated without brazil because there wasn't the certificate and when I have added the brazilian certificate and select "Continue distributing to current markets", the list must have not been updated.

So, to resolve my probleme, I just re-select "Distribute to all available marcket at the base price tier", in the Windows Phone Dev Center, with the brazilian certificate and the list must have been re-genenated.